# Data rectangling? - How do I reshape/collapse multiple rows of data based on a unique identifier into one cell in R?

Tags: r, reshape, tidyr

I'm looking to take multiple rows of data and collapse them into one cell per unique identifier.  I'm working with a fairly messy, decent sized data frame but a very simple example of what I am trying to accomplish is below:

```
mydf = data_frame(x=c(rep("A",3),rep("B",3),rep("C",3)),
                  y=letters[1:9])

mydf
# A tibble: 9 x 2
  x     y    
  <chr> <chr>
1 A     a    
2 A     b    
3 A     c    
4 B     d    
5 B     e    
6 B     f    
7 B     g    
8 B     h    
9 B     i
```

I want to run some code...ideally through some use of the `tidyverse` like `mydf %>% mutate(y = I'm really not sure, maybe one of the map functions)` and then the final data frame looks like this:

```
better = data_frame(x=c("A","B","C"),
                    y=list(c(letters[1:3]),c(letters[4:6]),c(letters[7:9])))
better
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  x     y        
  <chr> <list>   
1 A     <chr [3]>
2 B     <chr [4]>
3 C     <chr [3]>

better$y
[[1]]
[1] "a" "b" "c"

[[2]]
[1] "d" "e" "f"

[[3]]
[1] "g" "h" "i"
```

As previously mentioned, my data is much larger and messier and will, hopefully, end up in a Shiny app so it needs to completely autonomous thus looking for a solid understanding of the functions available to make this work.  I imagine it may require a few more steps than just `mutate`, possibly creating a separate data frame similar to `better` and then `left_join` it back to the original.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need a group by `summarise` where we wrap the 'y' in a `list`

```
out <- mydf %>%
        group_by(x) %>% 
        summarise(y = list(y))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  x     y        
#  <chr> <list>   
#1 A     <chr [3]>
#2 B     <chr [3]>
#3 C     <chr [3]>

out$y
#[[1]]
#[1] "a" "b" "c"

#[[2]]
#[1] "d" "e" "f"

#[[3]]
#[1] "g" "h" "i"
```

Comment: So simple!  For some reason I never think to use `summarise` for anything other quantitative summaries...

Answer (score 0):

Use the nest function from tidyr.

```
library(tidyverse)
mydf %>% nest(-x)
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  x    data            
  <chr> <list>          
1 A     <tibble [3 x 1]>
2 B     <tibble [3 x 1]>
3 C     <tibble [3 x 1]>
```